# Magento: Cannot retrieve payment method instance

Tags: magento, methods, paypal, payment

I recently started to have the following error when trying to proceed a paypal payment on my magento store:

> Cannot retrieve payment method instance.

I have read about it on various websites, and it seems to happened when you create/modify a payment method. However, in my case, it really started happening with no reason at all, as I have not made any changes to my website recently.

I have tried to manually force `paypal_standard` as method in the `sales_flat_order_payment` and `sales_flat_quote_payment`  tables, but it did not work.
Paypal express checkout doesn't work anymore neither.

Does anyone have an idea of how to reinstall/reset or something the paypal payment module?
Or to further debug the issue?

(I am not a programmer so I would need quite detailed information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having this issue, I have solved it by deleting the `/app/code/core`  folder and replacing it with a vanilla magento one. Most likely the paypal payement system module got corrupted for no reason and replacing it with vanilla version solved the problem.